# php - create pdf from googlemap contents using mpdf tool

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, mpdf

today I found `mpdf` tool to generate pdf from html, though I could generate pdf from normal paragraph, div etc. but I am interested to generate pdf from google map content..

I am using simplegooglemap api v3, in which I am generating map like this with marker

```
<?php
        require_once("simpleGMapAPI.php");
        $map = new simpleGMapAPI();
        $map->setWidth('500px');
        $map->setHeight('500px');
        $map->addMarker("48.983307", "72.808907","My first marker","");
        $map->printGMapsJS();
        $map->showMap(true); 
?>
```

Please someone help me to generate pdf from google map

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is; instead of loading the Google maps api directly in browser - use their [Google Maps Image APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/)

So, your html will look something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a test.</h1>
        <p>We are located here:</p>
        <img width="200" height="200" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-15.800513,-47.91378&zoom=11&size=200x200&sensor=false">
    </body>
</html>
```

This way, the mpdf library should be able to download and load the image source and embed it into the PDF as a normal image.

---

If you need markers on the static map image for your in-line include; take a look at this:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=en#Markers

Comment: but I have more than 1 marker sometimes 50-100 marker, please suggest

Comment: According to the documentation, this is allowed; `markers=markerStyles|markerLocation1| markerLocation2|... etc.`

Comment: Static map has limit in URL length (~2000 symbols), so you cant place there 50-100 markers